# Ajax call to wait for listener script to complete and notify user

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a program that will let the user submit a test case from a webpage (main.php), the webpage will send an ajax request to insert a row in MySQL with user data (insert.php) with `done=0`. I then have a listener script (testexec.php) that runs every minute on a crontab to process/run (ssh into each server and run the test on the server) the test cases on each server and update the row to `done=1` after the test is completed.

My ajax call will finish right away after the insert of the row is complete and will tell the user to wait.

I want to be able to let the user know when the listener script is finished with their test case and display the result back the page.

Here is my AJAX call:

main.php

```
 //POST the data to insert.php
    $.ajax({
        url:"insert.php",
        type: "POST",
                  data: {
                      gateway: $("#gateway").val(),
                      option: $('input[type=radio]:checked').val() 
                  },
                  dataType: "text", 
                  success:function(result){
                      $('#div0').html("Your test is being processed, please wait..");
                      //clearInterval(interval);
                      console.log(result);
                      alert('Test case submitted!');
                  }
              });
                 return true;
            }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the value of the 'responseText' value of the AJAX request. That way it will be synchronous.

```
//POST the data to insert.php
         return $.ajax({
              url:"insert.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: {
                  gateway: $("#gateway").val(),
                  option: $('input[type=radio]:checked').val() 
              },
              dataType: "text"
          }).responseText
```

Comment: This will return the responseText from the result of insert.php?

Answer (score 1):

You either set another ajax call on a timed interval to poll your server every few seconds and have the server return the result once its ready and clear the interval on the ajax call as part of the success function, or you create an event listener / websocket connection to the server and flush server output once it's available

Or, you incorporate the running of the test script into your php ajax handler script, increase the timeout on the ajax call if necessary and dont return any output until the test script finishes

Comment: Hi, I think the interval poll seems like a good idea. After the test is done, it will create an log output on the server with the results actually, how would I return the results back to my ajax (main.php)?

Comment: Are you going to store the output in the database too? You need to implement some method if identifying the user so you can return the relevant test result to them. main.php appears to contain no php at all, so to keep things simple I suggest you create  report.php and poll that with your 2nd ajax call. Have it return 0 if test is not finished and return the html for the result if test is finished then in ajax success handler set if data == 0 do nothing else insert data into an element on the page

Comment: Actually, I do have one liner php for autosearch in the `main.php` I just edited my code and put the complete code above. But I kinda get what you are saying. But I still quite can't get my head around how the reports.php is going to get the results of the test. My testexec.php basically runs the test and then flushes the stream until the stream is closed. I have another script that will output the result to a text file on the server. How exactly is `reports.php` going know when the output stream has ended and there is a report? Are you saying to store in mysql and have reports.php query it?

Comment: When the stream is closed then it will change the done=1.

Comment: or have the script which creates the text file store the filename in the database and change done to 1. Then report.php queries the database and if done=1 it loads the file with filename stored in that database row and outputs it to the ajax call

Comment: hmm... good idea, so the 2nd ajax call will trigger reports.php and reports.php will query mysql database for the file name. One question though, the file will be stored on a remote server, so in order for main.php to display it on the webpage, it will have to transfer that file to the webserver right?